# WordPress pop-up that can be edited from dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I'm making this wordpress website

[image]

but the text in the middle is hardcoded into the html as 3 divs that are all loaded but visibility is set to invisible in css unless the user clicks the text on the right. The boss wants them editable by the client eg they can add more from the dashboard. So I have made those "ABOUT" etc bits pages that are editable from the dashboard (which means about , whats there etc are now full pages with a new menu and everything that is the same as the other pages), and the right hand side menu is a menu that is editable from the dashboard full of the pages they make, and all pages have the same template because i edited "page.php". It's instantiated with this:  'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>. Now there is a load time problem when they click about, whats there, upcoming, it takes a few milliseconds to load the whole page, even the menu is being reloaded now. We wanted the effect it has on the older site that did not load a whole new page, just has all the "ABOUT" etc as divs on one page, we want that menu etc not to have to reload. Not sure if we can either load all url's somehow or make the pages in the middle  be the only new url, like a popup page, and the content like the background image and side menu is on the same base page that doesnt reload. Cheers

Comment: So just to clarify, page.php is still outputting the three `div`s with the correct content, and it's just a matter of not reloading the page?

Comment: @acobster No. page.php has an article which is the admins article they wrote in the dashboard. I can't have page.php having all the divs when they are editable from the dashboard I don't think

Answer (score 0):

You need to either:

1.) load each page's content via AJAX into the dynamic div ([tutorial](http://stanislav.it/load-wordpress-post-content-with-ajax-and-jquery)), or

2.) use a custom `Walker` to output a toggle-able content div for each page in the menu, and use javascript to display them:

- Walker reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker
- JavaScript (uses jQuery) http://jsfiddle.net/4hsUd/